# How to configure memcached on linux ami ec2 instance

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, memcached, amazon-ami

I have linux ami running on ec2 instance, I am trying to install memcached but it failed 
display in "phpinfo()", here is what i have done so far.

installed memcached by :

```
yum install memcached
```

Added following line in my php.ini

```
extension=memcached.so
```

started memcached:

```
service memcached start
```

restarted apache

```
service httpd restart
```

When i do phpinfo(), memcached is not listed.
please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have installed the daemon, but not the php extension. You have two options.

1. Install via package manager if available `yum install php-pecl-memcached`.
2. Install via pecl `pecl install memcached`. You may need to install gcc and php-devel packages for this option to work.